# How to use cosine similarity within triplet loss

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, loss-function

The triplet loss is defined as follows:

```
L(A, P, N) = max(‖f(A) - f(P)‖² - ‖f(A) - f(N)‖² + margin, 0)
```

where `A=anchor`, `P=positive`, and `N=negative` are the data samples in the loss, and `margin` is the minimum distance between the anchor and positive/negative samples.

I read somewhere that `(1 - cosine_similarity)` may be used instead of the `L2 distance`.

Note that I am using `Tensorflow` - and the cosine similarity loss is defined that When it is a negative number between -1 and 0, 0 indicates orthogonality and values closer to -1 indicate greater similarity. The values closer to 1 indicate greater dissimilarity. So, it is the opposite of cosine similarity metric.

Any suggestions on how to write my triplet loss with cosine similarity?

**Edit**

All good stuff in the answers (comments and answers). Based on all the hints - this is working ok for me:

```
 self.margin = 1
 self.loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)
 ap_distance = self.loss(anchor, positive)
 an_distance = self.loss(anchor, negative)
 loss = tf.maximum(ap_distance - an_distance + self.margin, 0.0)
```

I would like to eventually use the tensorflow addon loss as @pygeek pointed out but I haven't figured out how to pass the data yet.

**Note**
To use it standalone - one must do something like this:

```
cosine_similarity = tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity()
cosine_similarity.reset_state()
cosine_similarity.update_state(anch_prediction, other_prediction)
similarity = cosine_similarity.result().numpy()
```

**Resources**

[pytorch cosine embedding layer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss.html)

[tensorflow cosine similarity implmentation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/losses.py#L2202-L2272)

[tensorflow triplet loss hard/soft margin](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/triplet_hard_loss?hl=pl)

Comment: The loss should decrease regardless; try a smaller learning rate. But you want the anchor and positive points to be drawn closer together, and you want the anchor and negative points to be driven further apart. So it seems like you want to subtract `cos_sim(A,P)` and add `cos_sim(A,N)`. You can shift them by 1 or scale them however you want, but it probably doesn't matter because that can also be reflected by a change in the margin. So maybe something like `L(A, P, N) = max((cos_sim(N,P) - cos_sim(A,P) + margin, 0)`. Make sure the margin is reasonable given the range of cosine similarity.

Comment: Is this what you’re looking for—just pass in “angular” for the  distance_metric parameter ? https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/triplet_hard_loss?hl=pl

Comment: @pygeek Yes - but I am not seeing how to pass anchor, positive, and negative. Do you have an example by chance?

Comment: @pygeek Standalone usage that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `Cosine_distance = 1 - cosine_similarity`. The distance and similarity are different. This is not correctly mentioned in some of the answers!

Secondly, you should look at the TensorFlow code on how the `cosine similarity loss` is implemented https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/losses.py#L2202-L2272, which is different from PyTorch!!

Finally, I suggest you use existing loss: You should replace the `|| ... ||^2` with `tf.losses.cosineDistance(...)`.

Comment: Yes this is working ok for me                                 



   `self.loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)
   ap_distance = self.loss(anchor, positive)
   an_distance = self.loss(anchor, negative)
   loss = tf.maximum(ap_distance - an_distance + self.margin, 0.0)`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that what you red about replacing L2 with cosine origins from the definition of cosine between two vectors:

```
cos(f(A), f(P)) = f(A) * f(P)/(‖f(A)‖*‖f(P)‖)
```

where dot product along the feature dimension is implied in the above. Next, note that

```
[1 - cos(f(A), f(P))]*‖f(A)‖*‖f(P)‖ = ‖f(A) - f(P)‖² - (‖f(A)‖ - ‖f(P)‖)²
```

which gives a hint on where the notion comes from when `‖f(A)‖ = ‖f(P)‖`. So your formula can be naturally changed to

```
L(A, P, N) = max(cos(f(A), f(N)) - cos(f(A), f(P)) + margin, 0)
```

Your `margin` parameter should be adjusted accordingly. Here is some Tensorflow code to compute the cosines for vectors

```
def cos(A, B):
    return tf.reduce_sum(A*B, axis=-1)/tf.norm(A, axis=-1)/tf.norm(B, axis=-1)
```

Whenever this loss would benefit your particular problem depends on the problem, so good luck with your experiments.